# Routing error after upgrading to Rails 3.2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently upgraded my app to the asset pipeline while on Rails 3.2.11, and in the process decided to use the [Heroku Rails Deflate gem](https://github.com/mattolson/heroku_rails_deflate) to help with gzip compression and cache control headers on the Cedar stack. There were dependency issues so I had to upgrade to Rails 3.2.14.

After the upgrade, I could not run my tests or even start my Rails server. There error I get is:

```
missing :action (ArgumentError)
/Users/mackshkatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@xxxxxx/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:178:in `default_controller_and_action'
```

The issue is fixed when I comment out line 3 in my routes.rb file:

```
Blogmutt::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'pages#home'
  put 'reports/save_customer_tracking/'
```

I have no idea why this is suddenly breaking. I can start up the server with it commented out, but of course the form in my app that uses the named route generated from that line is now broken.

Why is this line suddenly broken?

Comment: Which version of Rails were you using before the upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the controller and action on your route? Something like `put 'reports/save_customer_tracking/' => 'reports#save_customer_tracking'`

Comment: @LeoCorrea That did solve the problem. Any idea as to why that is an issue though? A few lines later in my routes file I also use shorthand for a route `get 'reports/customer_subscriptions'` and that seems to be causing no problems. Thanks Leo.

Comment: @mbratch Rails 3.2.11 -> 3.2.14

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work on rails 3.2.11 as the tiny version is the one changing it shouldn't have backwards compatibility issues.